# ElectronJs: How to use sequelize in rendrer process in windows?

Tags: node.js, electron, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with MariaDB in my desktop app windows 7. However the renderer process cannot access sequelize or any models defined in the model files.

This problem does not occur in Linux. I only have to create the sequelize object in the main process and authenticate there only once. After that this it is available for any page in the renderer process.

When I do the debugging, I found that the main page (index.html) loaded into the renderer has to re-authentcate the sequelize connection. But the problem here is when I browse to another page through the main page links, sequelize connection not available again. Also I can't re-authenticate since renderer already authenticated once. Here is my original code and debug code I ran.

**main process:**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const connectStr = 'xxxxxx' //hidden for security purpose
const sequelize = new Sequelize(connectStr)

function createWindow() {
    sequelize.authenticate().then(promise => {
          console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
          let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
              webPreferences: {
                  nodeIntegration: true,
                  zoomFactor: 1.0
              }
          })

          mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
          // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
    }).catch(err => {
          console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
    })
}

app.allowRendererProcessReuse = true
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

**renderer process: (works with linux, but not windows)**

```
const {remote} = require('electron')
const mainProcess = remote.require('./main')
const Bank = require('../models').Bank

$(document).ready(() => {
    Bank.findAll({}).then(banks => { //code })
})
```

Here is the **debug code** I put in js file of index.html

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const Bank = require('../models').Bank

const connectStr = 'xxxxxx' //hidden for security purpose
const sequelize = new Sequelize(connectStr)

//following will work here only once. Once visited another page this also fails.
sequelize.authenticate().then(promise => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
    Bank.create({
        name: 'CBL'
    }).then(done => {
        console.log('OK')
    })
})
```